# Regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex

I have following string

```
WA2ąą-02 -7+12,7. PP-.5P x0.6 words
```

and I need to count `words`, `number` and `sum` of all number using regular expressions.

Words:

```
WA2ąą-02
-7+12,7. 
PP-.5P
x0.6
words
```

Numbers:

```
2
-2
-7
12
7
-0.5
0.6
```

Sum of numbers should be `12.1`.

I wrote this code, and only word count works well:

```
import re

string = "WA2ąą-02 -7+12.7. PP-.5P x0.6    word"

#regular expresions
regex1 = r'\S+'
regex2 = r'-?\b\d+(?:[,\.]\d*)?\b'

count_words = len(re.findall(regex1, string))
count_numbers = len(re.findall(regex2, string))
sum_numbers = sum([float(i) for i in re.findall(regex2, string)])

print("\n")
print("String:", string)
print("\n")
print("Count words:", count_words)
print("Count numbers:", count_numbers)
print("Sum numbers:", sum_numbers)
print("\n")
input("Press enter to exit")
```

Output:

```
Count words: 5
Count numbers: 4
Sum numbers: 9.7
```

Comment: You want 12,7 to be 12 and 7, not 12.7, right? In some countries the , can mean decimal. Also, your string in code and the string in your question are different (one has 12.7 the other has 12,7).

Comment: I make mistake correct string schould be "WA2ąą-02 -7+12,7. PP-.5P x0.6 words", but I found solution, I use this regex for numbers:  r"[-+]?\d*\.*\d+"

Comment: Okay cool. Add it as an answer!

Comment: this works fine for 2....4 r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|[-+]?\d+"  one more thing, how I can found hex numbers starts with x or 0x  and replece them to decimal system

Comment: The sum is correct, just print out the list that you make it from, two of the numbers are negative. `[-2.0, -7.0, 12.7, 6.0]`. Only `-.5` isn't recognized because of the missing leading zero, which is a good decision in most cases, since computer output very rarely makes that shortcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex seems to work fine

```
([-+]?[\.]?(?=\d)(?:\d*)(?:\.\d+)?)
```

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'([-+]?[\.]?(?=\d)(?:\d*)(?:\.\d+)?)')
test_str = u"WA2ąą-02 -7+12,7. PP-.5P x0.6 words"
print(sum([float(x) for x in re.findall(p, test_str)]))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/NjxYtu)**

**UPDATE FOR `HEX`**

The following regex seems to work (assuming `hex` numbers do not have decimal in the string)

```
([-+]?)(?:0?x)([0-9A-Fa-f]+)
```

*Python Code*

```
p = re.compile(r'([-+]?)(?:0?x)([0-9A-Fa-f]+)')
test_str = u"WA2ąą-02 -7+12,7. -0x1AEfPq PP-.5P 0x1AEf +0x1AEf x0.6 words"

for x in re.findall(p, test_str):
    tmp = x[0] + x[1]
    print(int(tmp, 16))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/zfGnmB)**

*If there is any issue, feel free to comment*

Comment: @n1c9 yup..i want it..:)

Answer (score 2):

I think your `regex1` is good to go, it's simple enough.

```
regex2 = r'[-+]?\d*\.?\d+'
```

Seems to do the trick (but it's easy to miss edge cases with regex). Optional `-` or '+', followed by any number of digits, followed by optional `.`, then match at least one digit.

[**Regex101 Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mU9qH3/1)